# Unfamiliar syntax in python code sample

Tags: python, youtube

While reading through the code samples on Youtube API's in python, I encountered that line of code:

```
print 'Video category: %s' % entry.media.category[[]0].text
```

(https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python, in `Video entry contents` section)

What does `[[]0]` mean? Or is it syntactically incorrect?

Comment: This is syntactically incorrect code.

Comment: That's definitely a typo, which you could have found out by just copying this line into a python console (or just typing something like `a.b[[]0]`, which would result in the same error) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely the mistype. 
The correct piece of their api would be `print 'Video category: %s' % entry.media.category[0].text`:

```
def PrintEntryDetails(entry):
    print 'Video title: %s' % entry.media.title.text
    print 'Video published on: %s ' % entry.published.text
    print 'Video description: %s' % entry.media.description.text
    print 'Video category: %s' % entry.media.category[0].text
    print 'Video tags: %s' % entry.media.keywords.text
    print 'Video watch page: %s' % entry.media.player.url
    print 'Video flash player URL: %s' % entry.GetSwfUrl()
    print 'Video duration: %s' % entry.media.duration.seconds
```

Also, - https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3710 have a look at this issue. 
The answer from the support there - "Thanks for the report! Looks like there are a few instances of this in our older docs. We'll look into it."

Comment: If it's a mistype why does it return 11 times in the code with different variations!? for example: `authsub_token = parameters[[]'token' ]`, are you sure it's mistype?